# Input group addon alignment

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Why dont I see the input group addon just beside the textbox ?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  </head>
  <style>
    input
    {
      max-width: 280px;
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" />
      <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

What do I need to do to display the content of the span after the textbox adjacent to it without any gap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the max-width you are putting on the input. try putting it on the input-group instead like:

```css
.input-group {
      max-width: 280px;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
</div>
```

Comment: OK. But do you know why the span is not displaying adjacent to the textbox and showing as right aligned?

Comment: I have added code snippet - when you run it does it display correctly?

Comment: Yes it does. I just wanted to know why the content in the span get right aligned if the containing element is wider.

Comment: Oh, right. Its because of the bootstrap styling on the "input-group-addon" class. In particular: `display: table-cell;`